# What is the Ubuntu Server's relationship to LAMP?

Tags: server, lamp

Alright, I don't know if it's a good idea to challenge these two, is there any relation between them?
I understand LAMPP: it's the installation of Apache, MySql, PHP and Perl (or Python) on Linux.
But I don't quite understand what the Ubuntu server is.
Please, explain me what I can do with Ubuntu server and if it has any relation with LAMPP. (if yes, is it better than LAMPP?).
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu Server is the 'L' in 'LAMP'; that is to say, Ubuntu Server is a Linux-based Operating System (**L**) on which people run the Apache HTTP Server (**A**) with MySQL or MariaDB for data storage (**M**) and Python, Perl, or PHP for scripting (**P**).

People also run [Debian](http://www.debian.org/), [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/), and [RedHat](http://www.redhat.com/rhel/) as their **L**. Ubuntu is growing pretty popular as a LAMP OS because of its quick installation and deployment, as well as five years of free LTS (Long Term Supported) support from Canonical.

Comment: Ubuntu also provides the *A*, *M*, and *P* components of *LAMP*. They are all Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

L -- Linux
Ubuntu is a Linux distribution. 
A distribution has a standard protocl for installing and removing applications, libraries and dependant files. This is called a packaging system.

Ubuntu uses Debian( another linux distribution) packaging system and apt tools to package and install the tools and applications used in the linux ecosystem more graphically user friendly and better integrated.

Ubuntu Server is the same linux distribution with packages tuned for deployment as a server. When using ubuntu server, one could get support from Canonical and have the benefits of tools like landscape for monitoring.

The main difference between having ubuntu server packages and using any other LAMPstack like would be the ease of upgrading and downgrading based on availability of packages.

Yes, using ubuntu server is better than using a LAMPstack. Better documented technique of hosting an application , more secure way of organising the filesystem and finally, the possibility of getting support from canonical support staff.