# Creating a Web Page in Ubuntu and accessing it through Ethernet from another Ubuntu user

Tags: networking, server, webserver

I'm creating a webpage in Ubuntu, in which simple files such as .txt can be uploaded. Now, I want to transform my laptop into an Ubuntu web server, through which any other Ubuntu or Windows user can access that specific web page through Ethernet connection.

How can I make my laptop having Ubuntu into such a web server?

How can I access that web page from another Ubuntu or Windows user via Ethernet? What are the necessary configurations or settings required for that?

Comment: This is a very simple question, but a nice one.

Answer (score 3):

Installing the `apache2` package in Ubuntu is all you need to host files, and most likely the easiest solution since it is available in the repositories and comes with basic configuration.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

After installing the package, a directory will be created at `/var/www`. Now each time someone tries accessing your browser from a browser will be welcomed by the index page of that directory.

By default, it contains an "It Works!" message, and it's located at

```
/var/www/index.html
```

If you remove that file, the browser will instead show a listing of files in that folder.

Thus each file you need to let other computers see in your browser should be located inside that directory.

It can be reached by `http://_YOUR_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS_/`

**Note:** By default, and for security reasons, the `/var/www` directory is not writable for any user. Check this question and answers for more details on that: [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

---

After installing Apache, you stop or start the service by typing one of the following respectively:

```
sudo apache2ctl stop
sudo apache2ctl start
```

---

Of course, this isn't all you can do with Apache, but as solution for your problem there isn't more that needs be done.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your answer n comment as well !!!! Can you tell me more about a LAMP server and Apache and where exactly they find their uses....and what differentiates them ??

Comment: @dhruvil25 LAMP just means Linux, Apache, Mysql & Php. So it's just apache with some extra stuff.

Comment: Check this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/92485/what-is-the-ubuntu-servers-relationship-to-lamp

Comment: Thannks again Dan. I'm going to build a database, too on a ubuntu desktop and I want that accessible from any pc. So I think I'm gonna need PHP and MySQL ????

Answer (score 1):

You need one web server like tomcat,glassfish or jboss then put your web page in their
deploy directory 
follow the following steps

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
wget http://mirror.atlanticmetro.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.29/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.29.tar.gz
tar xvzf apache-tomcat-7.0.29.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-tomcat-7.0.29  ~/path/to/tomcat
sudo vi ~/.bashrc
export CATALINA_HOME=~/path/to/tomcat
. ~/.bashrc
```

now go to your web servers bin directory and run the run.sh hile using

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

and before that just make sure that all the environment variable like JAVA_HOME and all that are properly configure and make sure that you and your web server containing device are connected in same lan network

now go to your web browser and type like

```
http://your_webserver's_ip:8080/your_webpage_name/
```

i think that's it it will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd jump to an application server for hosting simple static files.

Comment: you are well come

Answer (score 0):

Hi & Welcome to the community.

You can achieve this by setting up LAMP server within your Ubuntu distribution. To do this you may follow below official Ubuntu documentation;

- [LAMP - ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

I personally like Digital Ocean's article which is quiet interesting & also found one from How To Geek;

- [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)
- [How to Turn Your Home Ubuntu PC Into a LAMP Web Server](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42480/how-to-turn-your-home-ubuntu-pc-into-a-lamp-web-server/)

Once you've installed the server accordingly, you can access it locally within your PC. If that is all done, next is to check whether others can access it within the LAN/WLAN. Usually if the server is up & running with no errors. You may try accessing the IP of your respective workstation from another

> http:// your_pc_ip_address or http:// your_pc_ip_address:80 (or the specified port, default is 80 for HTTP)

I also found below article while searching which may help you.

- [LAMP server is not accessible from another computer on the same LAN](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1979921&page=2)

Hope this helps & make sense for you to achieve what you want.

Comment: If a simple webserver is needed to just host static files, there is no need to install LAMP. Both PHP and MySQL would be useless. Apache would be more than sufficient.